# How to parse a cron expression in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2, cron

AWS's `Write-ASScheduledUpdateGroupAction` API offers the ability to create scheduled actions within AutoScalingGroups, both one-time and recurring. I'd like to use it to create a more complicated schedule using the "Cron" -Recurrence option.

In AWS's [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Write-ASScheduledUpdateGroupAction.html), the -StartTime argument requires that it be set to a future date, but what isn't clear is that -StartTime is when the Scheduled Action will run the first time.

**My question**: what's the best way to parse a Cron expression in Powershell so that I can programmatically make -StartTime the first desired recurrence of this Scheduled Action?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers When I first made the API call, I expected the -StartTime/-EndTime to be the "time borders" for the -Recurrence argument (which they are), but -StartTime is also the first time the Scheduled Action will be run (ignoring the cron expression). I'm looking at a couple cron parsing projects in other languages to see if they can be ported to Powershell.

Comment: @JonathanGrubb, look here: https://github.com/Puchaczov/TQL.CronExpression or here: https://github.com/Puchaczov/TQL.RDL
I am author of both, since it's .net you could use it easly from powershell.